# it's possible to add a percentage when I download with retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I've this code:

```
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(GithubService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT).build();

            GithubService service = retrofit.create(GithubService.class);

            service.getAirport()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Airport>>() {
                        List<Airport> airps = new ArrayList<Airport>();

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            for(final Airport air : airps) {
                                realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void execute(Realm mRealm) {
                                        AirportR airport = mRealm.createObject(AirportR.class);
                                        airport.setId(air.getId());
                                    }
                                }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {
                                        Log.wtf("ok", "ok");
                                    }
                                }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable error) {
                                        Log.e("ok", "non vaaa");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Airport> airports) {
                            airps = airports;
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

and I need to put a download percentage because airports are so much..and so I want to put in a textview the percentage of the download (and I don't know how to do it in onNext() method) and the percentage of the realm adding in the airport...
It's possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: You should understand, that RxJava is not a networking library, and it can't download anything. You do it with Retrofit. You should ask about Retrofit.

Comment: @VladMatvienko sorry I'm at the beginning of RxJava-retrofit... I've edited the question..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this function to show download progress, combine by rxjava and okhttp, hope it helps.

```
private void initOkHttpClient() {
    mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(URL_JSON).build();
}

private void rxPublishProgress() {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mProgressDialog.show();

    mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(URL_IMAGE).build();

    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream;
                Response response = mOkHttpClient.newCall(mRequest).execute();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                    long len = response.body().contentLength();

                    String progress = "0";
                    subscriber.onNext(progress);

                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        progress = String.valueOf(total * 100 / len);
                        subscriber.onNext(progress);
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            LogUtils.d("onCompleted");
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            LogUtils.d(e.toString());
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final String progress) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you didn't use retrofit2, sure?

Comment: just added init okhttp function, retrofit also used okhttp, in other side, it just a wrapper of okhttp and gson imo.

Comment: and how could you use after the downloaded file?

Comment: Thanks, your question helps me to make a solution

Comment: this will show percentages only after the file has been downloaded.